# I have added JS function to prevent user to insert invalid date in datepicker. It is working but error alert box is not closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new to JS. I have added JS function to prevent user to insert invalid(like 99/99/0000) date manually in datepicker. I have written all the function and it is working as expected but somehow when you entered the invalid date it throws the error but that alert box is not closed it remains as it is. Please guide me here Thanks in advance.

Function :

```
    $(function() {
      var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
      var beginDate = $("#dobEdit").datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
        })

        .on({
          change: function() {
            beginDate.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
          },
          blur: function() {
            beginDate.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
          }
        });

      function getDate(element) {
        var date;
        try {
          date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
        } catch (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
        return date;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Really hard to read your code and understand your question? What alert box do you refer to? is it `alert(error);` if so what do you mean that it does not close

Comment: it means when I add the invalid date it showing me a validation message in the alert box but after clicking on the ok button I am unable to close that alert box

Comment: You mean the `alert` keeps coming back?  Remove the `alert` and use a `console.log` or some other non-intrusive alert eg [tag:sweetalert] - alert doesn't play well with `change` and `blur`

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank You for your reply. I have used this option but it's behaving the same. when I use console.log it is printing error messages into the console log

Comment: You'll need to create a [mcve] ([edit] and click `[<>]`) which *demonstrates* the issue.  I've taken your code as-is and put it in a fiddle, and it works fine - a single `alert` on bad format.  https://jsfiddle.net/vsLnhumj/  I've made some assumptions/guesses as to the version of jquery-ui, make sure you include the ones you're using.  Also make sure it is [tag:jquery-ui-datepicker] that you're using and don't have another datepicker plugin which is skewing your script.

Comment: @freedomn-m In my project, there is an older version of jquery ie 1.8.1. Also, I have checked the above fiddle example it is working fine in that but not in my case maybe there is an issue with the version.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to provide us with a way to reproduce it.  Ideally here in a snippet, but possibly in a jsfiddle.  I tried with 1.8.1 and it still works fine (1.12.1 of jquery-ui).  https://jsfiddle.net/52938rfu/

Comment: @freedomn-m Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237451/discussion-between-y2k-and-freedomn-m).

Comment: If you're unable to reproduce it, then there must be some *other* code on your page that's causing the issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m  maybe. I am working on a very old application so unable to track where it causing the issue. BTW thank you very much for your help really appreciable.